# Dbeaver restore database Error 1277 you need the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege for this operation

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, dbeaver

I'm attempting to import a .sql file to restore a database(hosted on AWS RDS) however this error keeps coming up.

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

Task 'MySQL restore' finished at Tue May 24 15:00:04 BST 2022
2022-05-24 15:00:04.035 - IO error: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
2022-05-24 15:00:04.035 - java.io.IOException: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.validateErrorCode(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:240)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.executeProcess(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:221)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.doExecute(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:260)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mysql.tasks.MySQLNativeToolHandler.doExecute(MySQLNativeToolHandler.java:47)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.lambda$0(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:81)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.RunnableContextDelegate.lambda$0(RunnableContextDelegate.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Ive followed the recommended action for this error and have changed log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter from 0 to 1 in my RDS parameter group which should give my DB the permission necessary however the issue still persists.

I have also seen advice regarding the DEFINER variable in the .sql file and other potential conflicts within the file itself however the file is that big that it take 1hr+ to load up in a text editor to edit and even then the shear size causes the text editor to crash without me being able to make the change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated so feel free to ask if Ive left anything out.

Comment: What's at line 18 in your .sql file?

Comment: SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0; I can make changes to the file however it just takes 1-2+ hours to load due to the size of the sql file